# How to check if object with some data is in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The programming language that I am currently using is `Vue`.
I have some demo code right here:

```
<template>
  <button @click="checkInList">Check</button>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";

export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const firstInput = ref("");
    const secondInput = ref("");
    const list = ref([
      { name: "lava", kind: "liquid" },
      { name: "air", kind: "gas" },
      { name: "water", kind: "liquid" },
      { name: "earth", kind: "object" },
    ]);
    const checkInList = () => {
      if (list.value.includes({ name: "lava", kind: "liquid" })) {
        console.log("array includes lava");
        // here I want to return the kind of that element, which will be liquid
      }
    };

    return {
      firstInput,
      secondInput,
      checkInList,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

So how can I check if `list` contains the object with name `lava` and then return the kind of that object, which will be `liquid`?

Comment: You should use `find()`, Check MDN docs here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and return field that you want:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const firstInput = ref("");
    const secondInput = ref("");
    const list = ref([
      { name: "lava", kind: "liquid" },
      { name: "air", kind: "gas" },
      { name: "water", kind: "liquid" },
      { name: "earth", kind: "object" },
    ]);
    const checkInList = () => {
      return list.value.find(l => l.name.includes(firstInput.value)).kind
    };

    return {
      firstInput,
      secondInput,
      checkInList,
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```css
So how can I check if list contains the object with name lava and then return the kind of that object, which will be liquid?
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="checkInList">Check</button>
  <input v-model="firstInput" />
  <p>{{ checkInList() }}</p>
</div>
```